# PHP não salva dados do formulário no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Estou iniciando no PHP e estou com problemas no seguinte código

```
<?php

define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
define("USUARIO", "root");
define("SENHA", "leonardo");
define("BANCODEDADOS", "estacionamento");
$conecta = new mysqli(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA, BANCODEDADOS); // CONECTA
if ($conecta->connect_error) {
trigger_error("ERRO NA CONEXÃO: "  . $conecta->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

 $curso_aluno    = $_POST ["curso_aluno"];
    $semestre_aluno = $_POST ["semestre_aluno"];
    $nome_aluno     = $_POST ["nome_aluno"];
    $email          = $_POST ["email"];
    $celular_aluno  = $_POST ["celular_aluno"];
    $tipo_veiculo   = $_POST ["tipo_veiculo"];
    $placa_veiculo  = $_POST ["placa_veiculo"];
    $tipo_veiculo2  = $_POST ["tipo_veiculo2"];
    $placa_veiculo2  = $_POST ["placa_veiculo2"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO alunos (curso_aluno, 
                                        semestre_aluno, 
                                        nome_aluno, 
                                        email, 
                                        celular_aluno, 
                                        tipo_veiculo, 
                                        placa_veiculo, 
                                        tipo_veiculo2, 
                                        placa_veiculo2) 
                   VALUES  ('$curso_aluno',
                            '$semestre_aluno',
                            '$nome_aluno',
                            '$email',
                            '$celular_aluno',
                            '$tipo_veiculo',
                            '$placa_veiculo',
                            '$tipo_veiculo2',
                            '$placa_veiculo2')"; // CONSULTA
$query = $conecta->query($sql); // RODA A CONSULTA
$conecta->close(); // FECHANDO A CONEXÃO
?>
```

O que acontece é que ele não está salvando os dados do meu formulário no banco de dados. O formulário, se assim desejar, pode ser consultado em https://leoliveira.xyz/CadastroEstacionamento , e está como abaixo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cadastro Estacionamento -</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <center><img src="img\logo.jpg" width="800" height="100"></center>
  <div class="container">

  <form class="well form-horizontal" action="inserir_dados.php" method="POST"  id="cadastro_estacionamento" data-toggle="validator">
<fieldset>

<!-- Nome Formulário -->
<legend>Cadastro de veículos</legend>

    <!--Curso -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Curso</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></span>
    <select name="curso_aluno" id="curso_aluno" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
      <option value=" " >selecione seu curso</option>
      <option>Automação Industrial</option>
      <option>Gestão Empresarial</option>
      <option>Gestão da TI</option>
      <option>Manutenção Industrial</option>
      <option>Produção Fonográfica</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
      <!-- Semestre -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Semestre</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="semestre_aluno" id="semestre_aluno" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
      <option value=" " >selecione seu semestre</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Formulário Nome-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nome</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="nome_aluno" id="nome_aluno" placeholder="nome completo" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Formulário Email-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="endereço de email" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Formulário Telefone-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Celular</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="celular_aluno" id="celular_aluno" placeholder="apenas números com ddd" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Formulário RA-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">R.A.</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
  <input name="ra_aluno" id="ra_aluno" placeholder="apenas números" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Tipo de veículo -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tipo de Veículo</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
    <select name="tipo_veiculo" id="tipo_veiculo" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
      <option value=" " >selecione o tipo</option>
      <option>Carro</option>
      <option>Moto</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Placa do Veículo-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Placa</label>
   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></i></span>
  <input name="placa_veiculo" id="placa_veiculo" placeholder="placa do veículo" class="form-control" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Tipo de veículo 2-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Possui segundo veículo?</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
    <select name="tipo_veiculo2" id="tipo_veiculo2" class="form-control selectpicker">
      <option value=" " >selecione o tipo</option>
      <option>Carro</option>
      <option>Moto</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Placa do Veículo 2-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Placa do segundo veículo</label>
   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></i></span>
  <input name="placa_veiculo2" id="placa_veiculo2" placeholder="placa do segundo veículo" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Mensagem de conclusão -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Concluído! <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Dados cadastrados com sucesso.</div>

<!-- Botão Cadastrar -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Cadastrar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Como pode ser visto no site, o formulário não retorna nenhum erro e mostra a mensagem de que os dados foram inseridos com sucesso, porém nada acontece.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é fazer o [tour], caso ainda não tenha feito, e ler o guia de [ask]. Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: Domain has expired

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Por que não tenta assim?

```
<?php

    $curso_aluno    = $_POST ["curso_aluno"];
    $semestre_aluno = $_POST ["semestre_aluno"];
    $nome_aluno     = $_POST ["nome_aluno"];
    $email          = $_POST ["email"];
    $celular_aluno  = $_POST ["celular_aluno"];
    $tipo_veiculo   = $_POST ["tipo_veiculo"];
    $placa_veiculo  = $_POST ["placa_veiculo"];
    $tipo_veiculo2  = $_POST ["tipo_veiculo2"];
    $placa_veiculo2  = $_POST ["placa_veiculo2"];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','leonardo', 'estacionamento') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alunos VALUES ('ID','$curso_aluno', '$semestre_aluno', '$nome_aluno', '$email', '$celular_aluno', '$celular_aluno', '$tipo_veiculo', '$placa_veiculo', '$tipo_veiculo2', '$placa_veiculo2')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```